# Non-monotonicity of the simple Wojowu function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

The ***simple Wojowu function*** $\ W:\mathbb P\to\mathbb P\ $ is defined as follows:

$\qquad W(p)\ $ is the smallest prime $\ q\ge p\ $ such that all
$ \mod p\ $ residua classes are represented by prime interval
$\ p..q\cap\mathbb P,\ $ for every $\ p\in\mathbb P.$

> **Question** (an open problem): what is
> $$ \sup_{p\in\mathbb P}\quad W(p)-W(p'), $$
> where prime $\ p'\ $ is the smallest such that $\ p'>p?$

Numerical first examples of the values of $W$:
$$ W(2)=3\quad W(3)=7\quad W(5)=19\quad W(7)=29\quad W(11)=71 $$

> There is a plethora of related questions, and I'd be delighted
> to see them answered below.

Comment: There is a user here in MO called [Wojowu](https://mathoverflow.net/users/30186/wojowu)  ? do you mean the function of this person ? could you provide us a link about his titled function ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, yes, I mean our MO wojowu = Wojciech Wawrów ("Wojtek" is diminitive of "Wojciech"). The requested link is "https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372550/non-monotonicity-of-the-simple-wojowu-function".

Comment: the link points back to this question...

Comment: It's a strange loop!

Comment: I've faithfully fulfilled the @zeraouliarafik's request.

Comment: I'm curious before I'll take this Q. down, what's wrong?

Comment: Finding $p$ such that $\ W(p)\ge W(p')\ $ is already a challenge.

Comment: No match at OEIS, maybe someone should post it there?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, "no match" -- at one hand, exciting! On the other hand, I have several related functions (plethora :) ). There is no match for "5 9 4 17 20 20" either (I've avoided the initial "0 0 1 0") of the **basic** Wojowu function. This whole direction is fresh. I did a simple probabilistic computation but a simple model is either useless or otherwise wrong. After all, one would like to know WHY for a specific occasion W(p) > W(q) even when q is about twice of p (there are several of such examples).

Answer (score 1):

I'll present a partial numeric result; it suggests
the ultimate answer/conjucture (see the OP question) about
$$\ \sup (W(p)-W(p'))\ =\ \infty.$$

To compute simple Wojowu function $\ W(p)\ $ at a prime $\ p\ $
we may simply list the primes that follow $\ p\ $ until we exhaust all residua mod $p:$
$$ 2\quad 3=W(2)$$
$$ 3\quad 5\quad 7=W(3) $$
$$ 5\quad 7\quad 11\quad 13\quad 17\quad 19=W(5) $$

Note that for the first time we have a repetition of residua,
$\ 17\equiv 7\mod 5.\ $ This is addressed by the basic Wojowu function (this my answer here is the original reference to the
*basic Wojowu function*). Then again and for the last time
there is no repetition:

$$ 7\quad 11\quad 13\quad 17\quad 19\quad 23\quad 29=W(7) $$

Naively speaking, given two primes $\ p<q\ $ the list of residua (not counting the repetitions) of primes $\ > q\ $
starts higher (at $q$ rather than at $p$) and is longer at least by two. Thus one would imagine that $\ W(q)>W(p)\ $ virtually always. However, the repetitions are common and random enough to make function $\ W\ $ look more like a zig-zag than monotone as at the beginning:

$$ W(2)<W(3)<W(5)<W(7)<W(13)\ \mathbf{ =\ 103\ =}\ W(17) $$
$$ < W(19) < W(23) < W(29) < W(31) $$

Now, the picture gets different:
$$ W(29)<W(31)\ \mathbf>\ W(37)<W(41)\ \mathbf>\ W(43)
    \ \ldots $$
It's irregular. We even have a more distant decrease:

$$ W(31) = 577\ \ >\ \ 467 = W(43) $$

Soon, function $\ W\ $ decreases not once but even twice in a row:

$$ \ldots\ <\,\ W(107)\ \mathbf>\ W(109)\ \mathbf>\ W(113)
   \ <\ \ldots $$

> The word *simple* in the name *simple Wojowu function*
> reflects the syntax simplicity of the definition, e.g. there are no indices. However, I believe that the more basic is the
> ***basic Wojowu function*** $\ w(p),\ $ it's defined as
> the number of the residua repetitions:

$$ w(p)\ :=\ |\,(p..W(p))\cap\mathbb P\,|-p $$

Now we have $\ w(2)=w(3)=w(7)=0\ $ while $\ w(5)=1.\ $ Obviously, the basic function is even more zig-zag like (less monotonous) than the simple function.